# Split into chunks output from Solr analyzer

Tags: solr

When running the following query in Solr: `q=*:*&fq=name_with_synonyms:(some-word)`
I am getting an exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'name_with_synonyms:(some-word)': too many boolean clauses
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.parse(SolrQueryParserBase.java:217)
    at org.apache.solr.search.LuceneQParser.parse(LuceneQParser.java:53)
    at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:168)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:208)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$TooManyClauses: maxClauseCount is set to 1024
```

I don't want to increase maxClauseCount, and wonder if it is possible to split output of filter query into chunks to get something along the lines of `q=*:*&fq=category:1&fq=category:2&fq=category:3&....&fq=category:2000` as described [here](https://solr.pl/en/2011/12/19/do-i-have-to-look-for-maxbooleanclauses-when-using-filters/)

name_with_synonyms constitutes the following analyzer:

```
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English"/>
        <filter class="com.s24.search.solr.analysis.jdbc.JdbcSynonymFilterFactory" dataSource="jdbc/synonyms"
            sql="select synonyms from synonym" ignoreMissingDatabase="true"
            ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="1" generateNumberParts="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" generateWordParts="0" catenateAll="1" catenateWords="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
```